# Highcharts yAxis is not scaling to fill available height

Tags: highcharts

I'm having trouble with a chart where the height of the chart is not scaling to fill the area. The chart object itself is scaling correctly into the container div, it is the yAxis itself that is stuck in a shrunk state. I believe it has something to do with working with smaller numbers, but I'm not 100% certain

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Edit - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s27j6bp/1/)

```
"yAxis": {
    "min": 0,
    "categories": [],
    "title": {
      "text": "Hit Rate"
    },
    "stackLabels": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "labels": {
      "overflow": "justify"
    },
    "tickInterval":0.1
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Check this out. I have removed the "tickInterval". https://jsfiddle.net/9zh4x2oy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.tickInterval) :

> **tickInterval: number**
>
> The interval of the tick marks in axis units. When undefined, the tick interval is computed to approximately follow the tickPixelInterval on linear and datetime axes. **On categorized axes, a undefined tickInterval will default to 1, one category**.

If you remove the `categories: []` option of the y-axis, the graph is auto-scaled correctly.

EDIT : I didn't see you set a tickInterval, but the solution (removing the empty categories from y-axis) still solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Removing the empty category array & not setting the tickInterval solved my issues